# Can not save InkCanvas Content in UWP App into a SQLite Datebase when Release Mode turned on

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I have a problem with the saving of the content of an InkCanvas in a UWP App. In Debug Mode it all works perfectly. In Release Mode, I cannot save it.

The blob in the sqlite DB is empty all the time (in Release Mode).

Here is my Code:

```
static public byte[] GetByteArray(InkCanvas CardInkCanvas) {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    // Write the ink strokes to the output stream.
    using(IOutputStream outputStream = ms.AsOutputStream()) {
        CardInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(ms.AsOutputStream());
        outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Maybe a UWP pro can help me :)

Thanks Agredo

Comment: Could you check if the contents of the returned array are not empty?

Comment: its empty in release mode. In debug mode works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a problem with the saving of the content of an InkCanvas in a UWP App. In Debug Mode it all works perfectly. In Release Mode, I cannot save it.

Release Compiling use [.Net Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx) by default. So there are some different behaviors compared with debug mode.

In this case,`CardInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync` and `outputStream.FlushAsync` are async functions, you need to add `await` before them. So your codes should look like this:

```
static public async Task<byte[]> GetByteArray(InkCanvas CardInkCanvas) {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    // Write the ink strokes to the output stream.
    using(IOutputStream outputStream = ms.AsOutputStream()) {
        //Add await before async functions so that the async functions get executed before return.
        await CardInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(ms.AsOutputStream());
        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Function must be declared `async` as well.

Comment: Thanks, but now my Code                                                                                                             byte[] strokeContainerArray = GetByteArrayAsync(CardInkCanvas).Result;                                                                              stops in Release Mode. In Debug Mode it works...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `async` and change the return type to `Task<byte[]>`. @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks for reminding. @Agredo, I've updated the answer, please try the updated codes.

Comment: it woud not work, when the method is not async. My Problem is, tha i dont now how to handle this task with parameter in my following Code. I want to save this result in my Database. but  I dont get the result of this method.`byte[] strokeContainerArray = GetByteArrayAsync(CardInkCanvas).Result;` In release Mode the App stopps. Seems the Task never finishes.

Comment: Please don't use `GetByteArrayAsync(CardInkCanvas).Result` use `await GetByteArrayAsync(CardInkCanvas)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. I dont now, why i am so dumb and did not use the await!